# Xamarin.iOS.dll' doesn't match this runtime, nfloat is mapped to double, expecting single

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I have a simple View composed of an input, button, and recyclerview.  User inputs a search string, hits button, recyclerview populates, and then the user clicks on a returned item for a context menu.  This all works fine and dandy on iOS, but I'm running into a problem I can't find anything about on android.

ViewModel command

```
public IMvxCommand<Item> ShowItemMenuCommand
{
    get => new MvxCommand<Item>(ShowItemMenu);
}
```

Layout

```
</LinearLayout>
<MvvmCross.Droid.Support.V7.RecyclerView.MvxRecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recyclerView_items"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@color/window_background"
    app:MvxItemTemplate="@layout/listitemreturnbasic"
    app:MvxBind="ItemsSource ReturnedList; ItemClick ShowItemMenuCommand" />
```

Everything works up until I go to click on a returned item.  The command is not ran, the app just closes without a Trace, and debugging stops, if I look through the logs the last thing that appears is this:

```
[Mono] Assembly Ref addref Xamarin.iOS[0xa85b8d40] -> System[0x857d3240]: 18
[] Assembly used for native types '/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.myapp.myapp/files/.__override__/Xamarin.iOS.dll' doesn't match this runtime, nfloat is mapped to double, expecting single.
```

I can't find any information on the error, and I'm not sure what is causing it as the command is never run in the first place.

Comment: Found out it only happens when hitting #if __IOS__

Comment: What happens in `ShowItemMenu`?

Comment: Just some conditional code preceded with #if __IOS__ and #if__ANDROID__.  I found out it's the iOS macro that's causing the error, the code itself is never ran, and the code order doesn't matter; as soon as the function is hit it crashes